# Acumatica Document Report (Invoice) title does not show value from Page Heading

Tags: acumatica

I hope someone could help me with this:
My problem is about the Acumatica report SO643000, (Invoice/Memo).
What I am trying is to move the document title (invoice title, company title, shipping address...) everything originally from Header Of GroupInvoice to PageHeaderSection1. 
what I want it to show the invoice titles at all pages. 
No value is showing up at the heading section.

[image: What I did]

[image: What the page is showing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to move all that information to PageHeaderSection1.
The reason for printing empty page header is that on the step of printing page header the program doesn't have the corresponding record of the ARInvoice and because of that is printing fields empty.
The only thing that you need to do for printing that header on every page is to set `PrintOnEveryPage` of that groupHeader to `True` like is shown on the screenshot below.
[image]